# Appending an element to another element which is generated dynamically by a third party plugin

Tags: jquery, image

I've got a slider which loads slides through Javascript. I need to add a DIV element (with a ID of "home_slider_overlay") through jQuery on top of these slides.

Problem is, about 50% of the time, my code to add the element is executed before the slider plugin generates the slides.

I tried to use the Imagesloaded jQuery plugin but for some reason it doesn't seem to help.

Here's the markup of the slider:

```
<div class="ls-wp-fullwidth-container" style="height: 500px;">
    <div class="ls-wp-fullwidth-helper" style="height: 500px; width: 1903px; left: -491.5px;">
        <div style="margin: 0px auto; visibility: visible; height: 500px; width: 1903px;" class="ls-wp-container ls-container ls-lightskin" id="layerslider_1">
            <div class="ls-webkit-hack"></div>
            <div class="ls-inner" style="background-image: url(&quot;http://my_site.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2014/04/slider-bg.jpg&quot;); width: 1903px; height: 500px;">
                <div style="left: auto; right: 0px; top: 0px; bottom: auto; width: 1903px; height: 500px; display: none; visibility: visible;" class="ls-layer ls-animating">
                    Slide content
                </div>
                <div id="home_slider_overlay"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is my jQuery code to add the extra element:

```
imagesLoaded( '.ls-layer', function() {     

        jQuery('#layerslider_1 .ls-inner').append('<div id="home_slider_overlay"></div>');      

    });
```

Comment: what slider are you using and what is the code that instantiates it? There may be an onlslider load option you can use to add it.  Also your html looks as if that div is already added, if so then you may want to change the id of the second one you're trying to add

Comment: Upon reading your comment I discovered that the plugin (LayerSlider) has event fallbacks available in the dashboard, where I could add my function. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you know the amount of slides that have to be added, you can do an interval that checks every 50ms or so if the slider has rendered eveything, and then run the jquery.

```
var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
    if($(".slide_class").length == amount_of_slides){
        $('#layerslider_1 .ls-inner').append('<div id="home_slider_overlay"></div>');
        clearInterval(interval);
    }
}, 50);
```